# Which Kanji for お手数をかける

Tags: kanji

What is the correct Kanji for かける in お手数をかける or 面倒をかける?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both 手数を/面倒を 掛ける

This Kakeru means "put something onto"
So the whole thing can be translated, put the bother/trouble on you.